# Use strong induction to show that every intger can be expressed as the sum and/or difference of 3's

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Use strong induction to prove that every positive integer can be expressed as the sum and/or difference of distinct powers of 3.

i cant figure out my base case i dont know how to imply the construction of one of the integers following one i pick. i know that every even number can be expressed by exactly 2 distinct 3's but the odds are harder i need to rewrite the question into a way i can actually imply induction to it.

Comment: It may give a hint how to approach it but i already tried sorting into things a multiple of 3 and not it didnt get me anywhere but ill try it again.

Comment: This is really proving that the "balanced ternary" expansion exists.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/751943/362009

Comment: i was kind of hoping for a hint not the whole solution but i closed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base case can be just $1=3^0$

Then strong induction allows you to assume that all values less than $n$ can be expressed as combination of single powers of $3$.

So for $n$ itself the nearest multiple of $3$ is either $n{-}1$, $n$ or $n{+}1$. So we have $k$ such that  $n\in\{3k-1, 3k,3k+1\}$ . Clearly $k<n$ so by the inductive hypothesis, $k$ can be expressed as a combination of powers of $3$. This give us that $3k$ is also such a combination, obtained by increasing by one the exponent on each power of $3$ in the expression for $k$. Note that expressing $3k$ does not require using $3^0=1$, since if $k$ requires such a term it has become $3^1$ in expressing $3k$. So then if necessary we can add or subtract $3^0$ to get a qualifying expression for $n$.